# Convert to array from the specified string

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a string with the below format. I would like to convert this string to array.But i don't know how to convert.

```
1395374478.195 {
    Channel     : 00000068
    State       : open
    Exten       : 100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Arrays are Collection of Homogeneous elements 
and You are specified Elements having Different Data Types
Instead Arrays You can Use Class Or Structure.
But As per Naming Convention in c# Class or Structure Can't Have Name like 1395374478.195

EDIT:

```
 class MyClass
    {
      private int  Channel    {get;set;}
    private string State       {get;set;}
         // private bool State       {get;set;}          For Boolean
        private int Exten       {get;set;}

        public void PerformAction()
        { 

        /// Your actions on above properties ...ex.. ON Channel,State For Adding,removing,or Any

        }

    }
```

Comment: k removed that number, then its possible?

Comment: Am new for .net.Please tell me how to get that values